# Rebuild Search Indexes timing out

Tags: search

After some issues with our host, our site has returned - but the search function hasn't.

Any search on either back or front end brings zero results - when the entries which fit the criteria do exist.

Each time I try and rebuild search indexes, I get a timeout, and my browser gives me an error - meaning I'd have to try again.

Any ideas of what I can try would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Craft 3.1.2 added an index-assets console command that you can use instead of the web-based utility. (#3595)

Sounds like that will work better for you :)

Run this to learn more about it:

```
./craft index-assets --help
```

Comment: Alas I'm still running Craft 2 and at this time can't do anything about an upgrade. But thank you very much for taking the time to answer.